# One Log4j for two Web Applications

Tags: web-applications, servlets, log4j

I have two war files , one is client war file  and another is Axis2.war file.

Is it possible to have common Log4j for both these Applications (Means both using one Log4j.properties file )

Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to place Log4J JAR in common directory (like `/lib` in Tomcat) and remove it from `/WEB-INF/lib` directories inside both WARs. Now place `log4j.xml` on the CLASSPATH, so it will be loaded upon servlet container startup, not the web application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just configure Log4j via the `PropertyConfigurator.configure(location)`, where `location`  may be a parameter passed to tomcat via `-Dlog.location` or configured in each application to point to the same file.

Do that configuration in a `ServletContextListener`.